# Bac à sable expérimental — Experimentation Sandbox

Tags: support

Ceci est un bac à sable pour expérimentations diverses avec les fonctionnalités de SE.
Il est similaire au [Formatting Sandbox](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox) fourni sur Meta Stack Overflow.

(Utile pour jouer avec la ponctuation et l'espacement par exemple.)

---

This is a sandbox post for experimenting with SE features, similar to the [Formatting Sandbox](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox) on Meta Stack Overflow

(Might be used to play arround with punctuation and spacing.)

Comment: Bonne idée, je voulais justement tester [les liens](http://www.google.com) dans les commentaires. OK.

Comment: Et ceci devrait passer en commentaire http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/1211/pourquoi-les-animaux-ont-ils-des-noms-differents-dans-lassiette

Answer (score 1):

Testons les espaces insécables et les espaces fines insécables d'unicode : « ici » et là !

Ce n'est pas pareil que : « ici » et là !

Answer (score 1):

“*bla*”, *bla*! *bla*… {*bla*}, [*bla*], *bla*/*bla* and |*bla*|!

bla*bla*bla and *bla*bla*bla*.

+*tata*+

Comment: “*bla*”, *bla*! *bla*… {*bla*}, [*bla*], *bla*/*bla* and |*bla*|!

Comment: *bla*-*bla*-*bla*.

Comment: “<em>bla</em>” | <em>bla</em>

Comment: (*bla*), [*bla*], *bla*/*bla* and |*bla*|!

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/164146/inconsistency-of-markdowns-wrt-italics-and-punctuation

Comment: one more: |*bla*|

Comment: one more: +*tata*+

Answer (score 0):

Ceci ne devrait pas être une réponse triviale donc voici du texte de remplissage. Toute application linéaire est entièrement définie par son action sur une base.

[Pourquoi les animaux ont-ils des noms différents dans l'assiette ?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/1211/pourquoi-les-animaux-ont-ils-des-noms-differents-dans-lassiette)

pour l'autonommage des liens SE.

Answer (score 0):

Curieux, ces commentaires…​​​​

Comment: *bla*​…​​​​​​​​​

Answer (score 0):

Petit essais avec les tirets :

- quand on demande des puces avec l'interface
- encore

Avec des tirets quadratins sans ligne vide :

— un
 — deux

Avec des tirets quadratins avec une ligne vide :

— un

— deux

Answer (score 0):

A [chat] link, which I expect may lead chez Cosette.

Comment: A comment [chat] link.

Comment: `[about]`=[about] `[tour]`=[tour] `[meta-about]`=[meta-about] `[meta-tour]`=[meta-tour]